# Copy constructor in C++ for later use in a function

Tags: c++, object, copy-constructor

I looked through different thread and I have a hard time understanding how to utilize copy constructor.

If I want to manipulate my class, but I need to have original values to do so, I have to create a copy.

```
    class object {
           public:
           int member[5][5];

           object(object&); <-- how do we create a copy here?

           void manipulate() {
             <<-- how do I call it here?
           }
};
```

I've been trying different things such as `object copy = object(object&)` but it does not work.

Comment: Just omit the copy constructor. The compiler will generate one for you. And it will do the right thing. As for your question, *which* object do you want to copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `object(object&); <-- how do we create a copy here?`

One simple way is to *omit* the declaration, and let C++ compiler do it for you. Since your object does not allocate resources in its constructor's body, C++ can handle creating the copy constructor for you.

> `<<-- how do I call it here?`

Like this:

```
object copy(*this);
... // Manipulate it here
```

Comment: What is the difference between object(object&) object(const object &source). I meant how the compiler interprets. I know about const correctness, but why we don't have 'source' in argument in first declaration

Comment: @DNamto Since the parameter name is not part of a function's signature (i.e. only the type is considered, not the name) you do not need to provide the name if you do not plan to use the corresponding parameter. One can always drop parameter names when forward-declaring functions, although this misses the opportunity to make your code self-documenting.

Comment: And then how do I call value from the copy and the manipulated object? For example member[1][1] will get values from the copy or the object? What I want to do is take avg of two nearby rows/columns of the copy and put the avg. in the object.

Comment: @DNamto The main difference is that one takes  `const` reference (the idiomatic form for the copy constructor) and the other one doesn't.

Comment: @latenight_help In the context of a member function `member[1][1]` refers to `this->member[1][1]` (compiler "gives" you `this->` part for free). If you need to manipulate the copy, access `copy.member[1][1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I've been asking for this entire time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
object( const object &obj )
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
      {
         member[i][j] = rhs.member[i][j];
      }
   }
}
```

Or you can write simply

```
object( const object &obj ) = default;
```

because your copy constructor does not do something special.

As for its using then you may use it the following way

```
object one;
onject two( one );
```

or

```
object one;
onject two = one;
```

or even as

```
object one;
onject two { one };
```

or

```
object one;
onject two = { one };
```

Also take into account that if you explicitly defined the copy constructor then you should explicitly define the default constructor if you need to have it.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor is usually created because you cannot use the one generated by the compiler.  In such a case, you will usually copy each member one by one.

For example (written on the fly - not sure if it would even compile with errors/warnings)

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    A(const A& src)
    {
        m_array = (char*)new char[src.m_arraySize];
        memcpy(m_array, src.m_array, src.m_arraySize);
        m_arraySize = src.m_arraySize;
    }
private:
    char* m_array;
    int m_arraySize;
};
```